# Do we have a blog? (If not, when do we get it?)

Tags: support

Some SE sites have a community blag — do we have one yet that we could start publishing on? Do we have to wait until we're out of beta for it or something?

Many of our users have valuable stories they might like to share, and often do, about their experiences with coffee, especially from stuff they've found on this site! It might be valuable to make the community blog available for people to share stuff independent of any need to answer a question.

Answer (score 6):

No, and [never](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244467/were-no-longer-starting-new-individual-site-community-blogs-heres-why), I'm afraid. This doesn't mean we can't have an unofficial one, or start a community on Medium or something equivalent. It would be good to discuss what the community thinks we should do (if anything) on social media!

Comment: [*Nooooooooooooooooo!!*](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/)

Comment: The Medium thing is a nice idea. Whoever came up with that is a genius ;)

Comment: @abby What do you think I am, some kind of sock puppet?

Comment: How do you start an unofficial blog?